# Why does bash changes my question mark to hyphen?

Tags: bash

This bash script

```
i=0
var='bonjour ? hello' 
for v in $var
do ((i++))
echo -e "$i)$v"
done
```

will output:

```
1)bonjour
2)-
3)hello
```

not the expected:

```
1)bonjour
2)?
3)hello
```

Why ?

Comment: `for v in $var` expands each word in `$var` as a glob. `?` is a glob that matches any filename with only one character.

Comment: @axiac, you can reproduce it if you run `touch -` first.

Comment: BTW, `echo -e` is best avoided altogether. _Certainly_ don't use it if you don't have a specific reason to believe the `-e` will be useful (and even if you _do_ have a specific reason to want `echo -e ...`, you're better off using `printf '%b\n' ...`, as described by [the POSIX standard for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), a standard that doesn't allow a compliant `echo -e` to print anything but the exact string`-e` on output -- bash's implementation is _sometimes_ compliant, depending on the runtime flags that are active at any given time).

Comment: For a more in-depth discussion, see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo) over at [unix.se].

Comment: Is there any way to prevent "for" from expanding the variable. (If I use quotes around $var then for will not parse the "$var" in different words and treat it only as a single word)

Comment: Only by completely turning off glob expansion (which then needs to be turned back on later for your shell to operate normally). Better to avoid the problem -- _really_, use an array. (If you have a string as input, `read -a` can turn that string into an array for you).

Comment: what was the rational of this strange behavior: is there a useful purpose in applying glob to "for" ?

Comment: It's not specific to `for`. **All** unquoted expansions undergo string-splitting and globbing. All of them (except where in a specific context where it's suppressed, like the right-hand side of an assignment). There would need to be a good reason for something to _not_ undergo it.

Comment: The rationale _for bash_ is that the POSIX sh standard mandates it; bash has no choice if it wants to be a standards-compliant shell.

Comment: Thanks for this clear explanation

Comment: The rationale _for POSIX_ is that historical shells did it -- and there are reasons one could justify that historical behavior; `files='*.gif *.jpeg'; for file in $files; do ...` f/e

Comment: ...is it a bad decision in hindsight? Definitely. But if a shell goes and fixes all the standard's bad decisions, it ends up like zsh -- subtly incompatible with everyone else, and worse, where people writing code to be compatible with that shell end up in habits that make their code wildly buggy when they try to write code for any shell that hasn't made the same "corrections" to standard-mandated behavior.

Comment: In this example it seems my variable is always quoted. Where isn't it? i=0;var='bonjour ? hello' ;eval ay=("$var");for v in "${ay[@]}"; do ((i++)); echo -e $i"$v";  done

Comment: `eval` creates a second evaluation pass without your syntactic quotes. It's seriously bad juju; don't ever use it.

Comment: To explain what I mean by the above: When `eval ay=("$var")` is parsed, the quotes around `$var` are consumed _at that parse time_ to mean that the contents of `$var` shouldn't undergo string-splitting and glob expansion at that time (at the parse _before_ `eval` is actually run). So what's then _actually passed_ to the `eval` command is the exact string `ay=(bonjour ? hello)` -- the quotes were consumed before `eval` started so they're gone by the time the assignment actually runs.

Comment: See also [BashFAQ #48](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) for more re: the general "don't ever use eval" assertion.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you're expanding `$var` unquoted, which replaces `?` with a list of single-character filenames in the current directory. You evidently ran this code in a directory containing a file named `-`.

---

Lists of things should only ever be stored in arrays, not strings.

This lets you quote the expansion to suppress globbing and word-splitting, while still iterating over list elements:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
i=0
varArray=( 'bonjour' '?' 'hello' ) 
for v in "${varArray[@]}"; do
  ((i++))
  echo "$i)$v"
done
```

If your input comes in as a string, you can use `read -a` to convert it into an array without performing glob expansion:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
i=0
var='bonjour ? hello'
read -r -a varArray <<<"$var"
for v in "${varArray[@]}"; do
  ((i++))
  echo "$i)$v"
done
```